# Name Server Daemon (NSD), possible to use PostgresQL/MARIADB as backend for DNS zone data?

Tags: linux, networking, dns

Is it possible to store DNS zone data in a database with NSD? I have not found any documentation for that.

Comment: What about this? https://mysql-bind.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The link shows something for BIND, which is not NSD. Both are authoritative name server, but I am looking for a solution for NSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such complexity was explicitly *not* a design goal of NSD.

I've had a quick look at NSD's source code (haven't looked at that in *ages*, thanks for reminding me of it), and all you'd have to implement all  the interfaces in `namedb.h` that consume a `domain_table`, so that's mostly

- `domain_table_find` (your lookup),
- `domain_table_insert` (add/modify entry),
- `domain_table_count` (number of entries),
- (`domain_table_search` (closest match, which I consider an internal functionality *only* used by `domain_table_find`, but it's still "public" API in namedb.h, so that's something to discuss with upstream)) and of course
- `domain_table_create` (create database handle),

assuming you don't want nsec3 functionality.

Sounds like a fun weekend project if you just need to test whether this is feasible, sounds like a larger effort should you want to deploy this in production and be sure things work – in that case, you'd very much speak to the NSD maintainers and discuss whether you can upstream that functionality, add uni tests and CI services to make sure it doesn't break when people fix bugs in the rest of NSD or add features, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well, that is a bummer! I would be more or less keen on writing a shell script for such functionality, but before I do that, I have to evaluate further, whether NSD is the right tool, for our needs then. I kind of liked the database integration, that powerDNS and bind have, but powerDNS doesn't support different replies based on the source address and bind just feels to old!

Comment: well, the thing is that nsd is probably pretty fast and low in complexity – database in the process memory, no complex API to talk between database and query handler. Making a query to Postgres/MySQL, unpacking the result, and putting that back into the response would be as complicated and compute-intense as the *whole* handling of an average DNS request in its current architecture. Relational database servers are cool, and all, but if you can keep the whole state in RAM (and want to do that, anyways), fail over as complete system, and handle requests within one process:

Comment: they actually offer you nothing you need! (Sharding: if you need it, great. But typical large name servers are just packed with RAM, so that each of them is autonomous and can serve at more or less 100 Gb/s wire speed; replication, database failover: you have N name servers, not one, that's your redundancy right there; complex queries, full text indexes, query optimization…: you don't benefit from any of that when resolving names. You need a string hash table, that's it.)

Comment: I see and understand your argument. However, it leaves me wondering, how large companies (DNS providers) get their customers DNS entries, into their respective zone files. I would assume that they are saved in a DB, and then probably exported to a zone file. That would be something I could try to implement, with some shell scripting perhaps.

Comment: typically, the intermediary database *is* the zone file. In the case of nsd, you modify your zone file, you compile it, then you use the remote to tell nsd to reload. It's not really hard to parse zone files.

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarifying.